# Why is my Docker image of flask app not saving a file in folders

Tags: python-3.x, docker, flask, audio, html5-audio

I have made a flask app that translates speech from one language to another and for that, I must store the translated audio file in a folder; then the audio is played(in frontend) using the audio player in HTML. Locally everything works fine but the docker image or heroku app doesn't play any audio as it doesnt store any audio file in a folder. Dont know why it doesnt save the audio file for that request. How to solve this issue. [More info on my project](https://github.com/SohamRatnaparkhi/Transliterate) ;
[Heroku app](https://transliterate-ht.herokuapp.com/)

Following is code-block wherein I have written the saving part of my backend

```
   translated_text = translator(transcript, target)
   target = languages[target].lower()
   try:
       speak = gTTS(text=translated_text, lang=target, slow=False)
   except:
       return render_template("error.html", message = "Sorry, I didn't understand that. Please try again.")

   #? Using save() method to save the translated
   global i
   i += 1
   
   #? speech in capture_voice.mp3
   speak.save(fr"static\translated_speech\captured_voice{i}.mp3")

   return render_template('translator2.html', translated_text=translated_text, path = fr"static\translated_speech\captured_voice{i}.mp3")
```

Code block is of playing the audio in `translator2.html` which is being rendered by this function

```
<div class="play-sound">
        <audio controls="controls">
            <source src="{{path}}" type="audio/mpeg">
        </audio>
</div>
```

File structure locally

```
 - static
    - css, favicon etc
    - translated_speech
 - templates
 - app.py
```

DockerFile

```
FROM python:3.9.12
WORKDIR /app/
COPY requirements.txt requirements.txt
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
COPY . .
CMD [ "python3", "-m" , "flask", "run", "--host=0.0.0.0"]
```

Docker image making commands

```
docker build -t app:v1 .
docker run -p 5000:5000 app:v1
```

How to solve this issue?
Thank you.

Comment: I think you need to use mount or volume in docker,

you can run : docker run -p 5000:5000 -v mydata/dockerdata app:v1 
-------
mydata is : your dirctory in your system
dockerdata is where that you are saving the flask data

Answer (score 0):

You should mount a directory of the host machine to your container. All files will be available also after removing the container. Here it mounts your current directory to /app in container:

```
docker run -v $(pwd):/app -p 5000:5000 app:v1
```

Comment: Rather update your question then put it in the comment

Comment: It gives error that local volume name has invalid characters.

Comment: Are you on Windows? Then use your path: -v /c/path/to/your/dir:/app